# How to add image icons besides file names in ListView

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a list of files in a ListView. I am selecting a file and then doing some operation.
I want to add these properties with files displayed in listview

1. if currently selected file from listview is running , add an icon1 with that file
2. if currently selected file does not complete operation successfully then update icon of that file to new one.
3. similarly, if file executed successfully, add icon 3 with file name in listview.

can somebody help me ?
i am using winform , .net 4

Comment: Please __always__ tag your questions with the target you are writing for: WPF? Winforms? ASP?...?

Comment: @TaW I am using Winforms

Comment: Add the 3 images to an ImageList and refer to it!

Comment: I have added 3 images in imagelist.  it shows successfully. but now i want to change the icon of file after it is executed.how can i update it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an ImageList Control to your form.

Add images to the control.

Assign the imageList to your listView

```
listView1.LargeImageList = imageList1;
```

Now choose the image to be shown for the item you want using the image index..

```
listView1.Items[0].ImageIndex = 1;
```

.

.
You can programatically change the imageIndex property based on your needs, and the icon will be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try change data template of list view by adding image control, where bind Path to list of your icons.

Comment: This is WinForms, not WPF.